# Tips for golfing in Logo

Tags: code-golf, tips

Logo is a programming language that was designed back in 1967 that has great potential for creating graphics in relatively few bytes compared to other languages.

Logo is an educational programming language that utilizes [Turtle Graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics).

There are multiple interesting implementations of Logo including:

- [Apple Logo](https://applelogointroduction.wikispaces.com/file/view/Apple%20Logo.pdf/334025686/Apple%20Logo.pdf)
- [Atari Logo](http://www.atarimania.com/documents/Atari_LOGO_Introduction_to_Programming_Through_Turtle_Graphics.pdf)
- [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language) (my personal favorite)
- [Texas Instruments Logo](https://archive.org/details/tibook_the-texas-instruments-logo-manual)
- [UCBLogo](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/usermanual)
- And [many others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logo_(programming_language)#Implementations)...

In addition, multiple Logo interpreters can be found online.

This page is intended to be a hub for code golf [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) regarding any implementation of the Logo programming language.

[image]

<sub>Source: [The Great Logo Adventure](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Great_Logo_Adventure.html?id=9E0GXFoYr3MC) (1998) by Jim Muller</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## LibreLogo

**Shorten Color Definitions:**

It is [documented](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language) that colors can be defined by name, identifier, RGB value, or HEX code.

In the majority of cases, if you have the opportunity to use an identifier for a color constant, that is typically the shortest option.

On the other hand, a little known fact is that you can also use the decimal value to define a color, and you can occasionally save bytes.

**Color Chart:**

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+   +-------------+
| Name                | Identifier | RGB           | HEX      | Decimal  |   | Best Option |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|   |-------------|
| "BLACK"             | [0]        | [0,0,0]       | 0x000000 | 0        |   | 0           |
| "SILVER"            | [1]        | [192,192,192] | 0xc0c0c0 | 12632256 |   | [1]         |
| "GRAY"/"GREY"       | [2]        | [128,128,128] | 0x808080 | 8421504  |   | [2]         |
| "WHITE"             | [3]        | [255,255,255] | 0xffffff | 16777215 |   | [3]         |
| "MAROON"            | [4]        | [128,0,0]     | 0x800000 | 8388608  |   | [4]         |
| "RED"               | [5]        | [255,0,0]     | 0xff0000 | 16711680 |   | [5]         |
| "PURPLE"            | [6]        | [128,0,128]   | 0x800080 | 8388736  |   | [6]         |
| "FUCHSIA"/"MAGENTA" | [7]        | [255,0,255]   | 0xff00ff | 16711935 |   | [7]         |
| "GREEN"             | [8]        | [0,128,0]     | 0x008000 | 32768    |   | [8]         |
| "LIME"              | [9]        | [0,255,0]     | 0x00ff00 | 65280    |   | [9]         |
| "OLIVE"             | [10]       | [128,128,0]   | 0x808000 | 8421376  |   | [10]        |
| "YELLOW"            | [11]       | [255,255,0]   | 0xffff00 | 16776960 |   | [11]        |
| "NAVY"              | [12]       | [0,0,128]     | 0x000080 | 128      |   | 128         |
| "BLUE"              | [13]       | [0,0,255]     | 0x0000ff | 255      |   | 255         |
| "TEAL"              | [14]       | [0,128,128]   | 0x008080 | 32896    |   | [14]        |
| "AQUA"              | [15]       | [0,255,255]   | 0x00ffff | 65535    |   | [15]        |
| "PINK"              | [16]       | [255,192,203] | 0xffc0cb | 16761035 |   | [16]        |
| "TOMATO"            | [17]       | [255,99,71]   | 0xff6347 | 16737095 |   | [17]        |
| "ORANGE"            | [18]       | [255,165,0]   | 0xffa500 | 16753920 |   | [18]        |
| "GOLD"              | [19]       | [255,215,0]   | 0xffd700 | 16766720 |   | [19]        |
| "VIOLET"            | [20]       | [148,0,211]   | 0x9400d3 | 9699539  |   | [20]        |
| "SKYBLUE"           | [21]       | [135,206,235] | 0x87ceeb | 8900331  |   | [21]        |
| "CHOCOLATE"         | [22]       | [210,105,30]  | 0xd2691e | 13789470 |   | [22]        |
| "BROWN"             | [23]       | [165,42,42]   | 0xa52a2a | 10824234 |   | [23]        |
| "INVISIBLE"         | [24]       | N/A           | N/A      | N/A      |   | [24]        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+   +-------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

## LibreLogo

**Use Abbreviated Commands:**

Abbreviated commands, also called "short names," are used across most implementations of Logo.

Here is the full list of abbreviated commands for [LibreLogo](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#LibreLogo_programming_language).

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Full Command    | Short Command | Bytes Saved |
|-----------------------------------------------|
| forward 10      | fd 10         | 5           |
| back 10         | bk 10         | 2           |
| left 90         | lt 90         | 2           |
| right 90        | rt 90         | 3           |
| penup           | pu            | 3           |
| pendown         | pd            | 5           |
| position 0      | pos 0         | 5           |
| heading 0       | seth 0        | 3           |
| hideturtle      | ht            | 8           |
| showturtle      | st            | 8           |
| clearscreen     | cs            | 9           |
| pensize 10      | ps 10         | 5           |
| pencolor 0      | pc 0          | 6           |
| fillcolor 0     | fc 0          | 7           |
| picture [ ... ] | pic [ ... ]   | 4           |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

## LibreLogo

**Random Numbers:**

Use [`any`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#ANY) instead of [`random`](https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#RANDOM) when possible.

*Random Integer (0 - 9):*

```
x = int random 10     ; 17 bytes
x = int(ps any)       ; 15 bytes
```

*Random Floating-Point Number (0 - 9):*

```
x = random 10         ; 13 bytes
x = (ps any)          ; 12 bytes
```

*Directly Assigned to Setting:*

```
pensize random 10     ; 17 bytes
ps random 10          ; 12 bytes
ps any                ; 6 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

## LibreLogo

**Use `PAGESIZE` to your Advantage:**

> `PAGESIZE` is a variable that is dependent on the [Paper Format](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Page#Format) in LibreOffice Writer and returns an array containing the `[width, height]` of the page in points (`pt`).

This could be useful for a variety of situations, but I personally found it useful for generating a number without using the digits `[0-9]`.

https://help.libreoffice.org/Writer/LibreLogo_Toolbar#PAGESIZE

[image]

---

**Value Chart:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Paper Format           | PAGESIZE                                 |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| A6                     | [297.35433070866145, 419.75433070866137] |
| A5                     | [419.75433070866137, 595.4456692913386]  |
| A4                     | [595.4456692913386, 841.6913385826772]   |
| A3                     | [841.6913385826772, 1190.8913385826772]  |
| B6 (ISO)               | [354.2456692913386, 498.95433070866136]  |
| B5 (ISO)               | [498.95433070866136, 708.4913385826771]  |
| B4 (ISO)               | [708.4913385826771, 1000.8]              |
| Letter                 | [612.0, 792.0]                           |
| Legal                  | [612.0, 1008.0]                          |
| Long Bond              | [612.0, 936.0]                           |
| Tabloid                | [792.0, 1224.0]                          |
| B6 (JIS)               | [362.8913385826771, 516.2456692913386]   |
| B5 (JIS)               | [516.2456692913386, 728.6456692913387]   |
| B4 (JIS)               | [728.6456692913387, 1031.7543307086614]  |
| 16 Kai                 | [521.2913385826771, 737.2913385826771]   |
| 32 Kai                 | [368.64566929133855, 521.2913385826771]  |
| Big 32 Kai             | [396.7086614173228, 575.2913385826771]   |
| User                   | CURRENT PAGE SIZE                        | ← Current Paper Format
| DL Envelope            | [311.7543307086614, 623.5086614173229]   |
| C6 Envelope            | [323.29133858267716, 459.3543307086614]  |
| C6/5 Envelope          | [323.29133858267716, 649.4456692913386]  |
| C5 Envelope            | [459.3543307086614, 649.4456692913386]   |
| C4 Envelope            | [649.4456692913386, 918.7086614173228]   |
| #6¾ Envelope           | [261.35433070866145, 468.0]              |
| #7¾ (Monarch) Envelope | [279.35433070866145, 540.0]              |
| #9 Envelope            | [279.35433070866145, 639.3543307086613]  |
| #10 Envelope           | [297.35433070866145, 684.0]              |
| #11 Envelope           | [324.0, 747.3543307086613]               |
| #12 Envelope           | [342.0, 792.0]                           |
| Japanese Postcard      | [283.69133858267713, 419.75433070866137] |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
```